# Expectation of a normal variable given the difference of it and another normal variable

Tags: expected-value, variance

I have two functions $w_0 = \mu_0 + \epsilon_0$ and $w_1 = \mu_1 + \epsilon_1$
Where $\epsilon_0 \sim N(0, \sigma_0^2)$ and $\epsilon_1 \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$

Assuming that $\epsilon_1 - \epsilon_0 = v$

What is $E(\epsilon_0|v)$ ?

I have seen it solved as $\frac{\sigma_{0v}}{\sigma_v^2}v$

But it looks like it should be $\frac{\sigma_{0}^2}{\sigma_0^2 + \sigma_1^2}v$

Or could you go from one solution to the other?

Comment: I assume $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$ are independent?

Comment: $\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$Assuming that $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$ are independent and $v=\color{blue}{\epsilon_0-\epsilon_1}$, those two answers are equivalent, yes. This is because $\sigma_{0v}=\Cov\left(\epsilon_0,v\right)=\sigma_0^2$ and $\Var(v)=\sigma_0^2+\sigma_1^2$ (make sure you can show these!). (Currently you have written $v=\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0$ in your question but if you do that, then $\Bbb{E}[\epsilon_0\mid v] =\color{red}{-}\frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma_0^2+\sigma_1^2}v$.)